# Is there any way to store Magento 2 logs into database. Is it possible by overriding any functions

Tags: magento2, log

Is there any way to store Magneto 2 logs into the database? Is it possible by overriding any functions?

Comment: Error logs ?? instead of writing to logs files why didn't write those to DB. But I don't think it's a good option to write to DB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good way. I don't know what your purpose for this is but Magento log files are a lot, if you save it in the database this can have a huge impact on website performance.

Case if you save all log files in DB it will give full memory error when you query data